# How to give a user permission to create users and grant them roles to only one database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to give a user permission to create other users but can only grant them roles to a specific database of my choice using SSMS with a query

Comment: If you use contained databases, it is simple to setup. Please see this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-2017